# How can you change the cursor icon to signify an areas on a Google Chart is clickable?

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I know it is possible to change the cursor icon for a google pie chart, but can it be done for individual sectors of that pie chart?

I would like to be able to show a change in the cursor icon to signify that a region/sector/area on a google chart can be 'drilled-into'.  At the moment it's just the pointer and showing the hyperlink icon where appropriate is what I'd ideally like to be able to do.

Comment: How you know whether the slice can be drilled-into?

Comment: If there's a slice, there must be data that constituted that slice, so they are in effect, all 'drillable'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of a hack, but I made something up for this that makes a lot of assumptions.

Google charts doesn't let you put specific CSS on a pie chart piece, but it just renders SVG tags, so you can apply styles to the SVG directly.

The following style rules make a pointer cursor on any element that is a path, or a sibling of a path, which for a vanilla pie chart setup is only the pie slices.  The rule is also restricted by the ID so it isn't going to go messing with other SVG graphics on the same page.

The biggest assumption made here is that you want all pie segments to be clickable.

```
  <style>
    #myChart path {cursor:pointer;}
    #myChart path ~ text {cursor:pointer;}
  </style>
```

You could make a variation on this that applies the style by the colour of the pie segment like so:

```
  <style>
    #myChart path[fill="#3366cc"] {cursor:pointer;}
    #myChart path[fill="#3366cc"] ~ text {cursor:pointer;}
  </style>
```

Comment: This works a treat for pie-charts.  However, I'm displaying a dashboard of charts of all different types and I want to extend this technique to the rectangles that make up some charts.  The problem here is that all charts are positioned on a background rectangle, so the style is effective applied to the whole chart.  Any ideas how I can overcome this issue.  I've tried doing it by colour, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I now have it working using colour separation.  So long as I have a consistent background colour.

Comment: Like I said, it's kind of a hack.  It might also work by selecting based on other attributes of the element, but I haven't looked very closely at the SVG structure that the Charts API generates to be able to make suggestions.