# Google Chart - Dim all other series except the one on which mouse is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to plot graphs. I am new to the wold of UI development & javascript. I've looked on the internet & managed to get graphing going. I am in the need to do the below

1) I have a line graph that has 9 series in it. When I hover on any one series, I like the others to be dimmed

2) Wen I move the mouse away, the original look should be restored to the graph.

I have been able to find examples for highcarts mainly. I'm struggling to implement something similar for google charts. Could I please request help to implement  this?

Here is my code to plot the graph.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onresize = function(){
                startDrawingChart();
            };

            window.onload = function(){
                startDrawingChart();
            };

             startDrawingChart = function(){
                // Load the Visualization API AND the piechart package.
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"],callback: drawChart});

                function drawChart() {
                    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded FROM server.
                    var data_1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?php echo (implode(",", $array_0)); ?>]);


                    var options_line = {
                        chartArea: {
                            left: 70,
                            top: 61,
                            width: '95%',
                            height: '60%'
                        },
                        curveType: 'function',
                        //width: 1600,
                        height: 400,
                        pointSize: 4,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        visibleInLegend: false,
                        vAxis: {
                            //title: "GC#",
                            //logScale: true,
                            titleTextStyle: {
                                color: 'black'
                            }
                        },
                        hAxis: {
                            title: "TIMELINE",
                            titleTextStyle: {
                                bold: false,
                                color: 'black'
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            position: 'top',
                            alignment: 'center',
                            textStyle: {
                                color: 'blue'
                            },
                            is3D: true
                        },
                        series: {5: {type: "line"}},
                    };

{position: 'top', alignment: 'center'},
                        bar: {groupWidth: '3%'},
                        is3D: true
                    };

                    var chart_1 = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('plot1'));
                    chart_1.draw(data_1, options_line);
                }
            };
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the chart, this is easy.  Just use the `select` event and change all the other series' colours to a lighter shade. If you're interested I could possibly write an answer around this, but your question specified hover.

You could possibly use CSS selectors like [this completely different situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628774/how-can-you-change-the-cursor-icon-to-signify-an-areas-on-a-google-chart-is-clic/26634831#26634831), but it would be pretty complicated to write in straight CSS. I don't really know LESS, SASS, SCSS, or COMPASS to be able to say if these tools would make it any easier, but they might.

I would take the approach of putting a hover selector on the whole thing that changes the colours of the SVG elements that make all the series, and then write a more specific rule that sets your hovered-over series back to normal.

It's been my experience that making visual changes to Google Charts that are not implemented as features of the chart is difficult, because they don't put any id's or classes on anything. So you can use CSS or jQuery selectors to try and find pieces of the chart - using colours seems to be an effective way of differentiating the SVG elements from series to series - but it is possible that you will get false positives or miss elements with dynamic charts. Being different all the time makes them hard to test.

Comment: Hello Balrog - Thank you very much for the guidance. Given I'm new to to java script world, I think I'll do best with going by "select". Could you please help with answer for this piece please?

Comment: I'll try to fit this in this evening (Eastern Daylight Time). It should take me less than half an hour to mock up an example for you. If you want to try and hack away at it, there's an angular-specific example of how to do something that uses a lot of the same concepts at http://nicholasbering.ca/angularjs/2014/08/16/agc-hide-series/ It's pretty heavily angular-ized though, so I'm not sure if you'll be able to adapt it.